# Linear Transformations $ \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If $ T : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 $ is a linear transformation such that $ T       \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 12 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} $ and $ T\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 10 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}  $ then the standard Matrix $A = ?$

This is where I get stuck with linear transformations and don't know how to do this type of operation. Can anyone help me get started ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that $T$ is **linear**. That means that for any vectors $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and any scalars $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$T(av+bw)=aT(v)+bT(w).$$
So, let's use this information. Since
$$T       \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 12 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad T\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 10 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},$$
you know that
$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}+2\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right)=T\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -2 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right)=T\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
must equal
$$T       \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}+2\cdot T\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 12 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}+2\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 10 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 20 \\ 10 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
So, we know $T\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$. Do you see how to find $T\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$? Then use the same process to figure out $T\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$.

After doing that, you should know how to make the (standard basis) matrix for $T$.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding where you got the value 2 for your 'b' scalar and 1 for you 'a' scalar. Was that arbitrary? Or is it I'm not seeing it right...

Comment: Let's say we decide to start by finding $T\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$. We see that we'll want to find values of $a$ and $b$ that will make the bottom coordinate of the sum
$$a\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix} +b\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a+2b\\2a-b\end{bmatrix}$$ equal to 0 (so that we can later divide by the top coordinate, $a+2b$, to bring it to $1$).

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

Write every $\,v\in\Bbb R^2\,$ as

$$v=a\binom{1}{2}+b\binom{2}{\!\!-1}\;\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb R$$

Now, convince yourself that

$$Tv=a\,T\binom{1}{2} +b\,T\binom{2}{\!\!-1}$$

Finally, get the matrix representation for $\,T\,$ wrt to the given basis.

Answer (score 3):

(I assume that you want the matrix with respect to the standard basis). Let 
$$
v_1 = \pmatrix{1 \\ 2}\quad v_2 = \pmatrix{2\\-1}.
$$
Note that
$$
\pmatrix{1 \\ 0} = \frac{1}{5}(v_1 + 2v_2)
$$
So
$$
T\pmatrix{1 \\ 0} = \frac{1}{5}Tv_1 + \frac{2}{5}Tv_2
$$
This will be the first column in $A$.

Now do likewise to find the second column.

Answer (score 2):

since $(1,2)$and $(2,-1)$ are independence  vector so they can be a basis for $ R^{2}$.
and if you consider standard basis for $R^{3} \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.
According to Linear Algebra writed by Hofman & Kenzy:
$T_{\text non-stnadard}=[0,10;12,-1;-2,1](2 \times 3$ matrix)
that first column is $T(1,2)$ in standard basis $(T(1,2)=0(1,0,0)+12(0,1,0)+-2(0,0,1)) $
and second column is $T(2,-1)$ at standard basis $(T(2,-1)=10(1,0,0)+-1(0,1,0)+1(0,0,1)). $

then consider  A=[$\frac{1}{5}$,$\frac{2}{5}$;$\frac{2}{5}$,$\frac{-1}{5}$]
(first column is coordinates of $(1,0)$ in base${(1,2),(2,-1)})$
and second column is coordinate of $(0,1)$ in base $\{(1,2),(2,-1)\}$

$T_{\text non-standard} *A $is matrix $T$ at standard basis .